# Find the smallest most common value, if all common values are same, find either first zero or next smallest number

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, numbers

Find the smallest most common value, if all common values are same, find either first zero or next smallest number.

Exclude using CommonsFinished to indicate which values to ignore completely as they are not useful (completely finished rows).

Here is the code I got, doesn't do a good job

```
Dim ColumnValues As New List(Of Integer)
Dim ColumnsFinished As New List(Of Boolean)

ColumnValues.Clear()
ColumnValues.Add(2)
ColumnValues.Add(1)
ColumnValues.Add(2)
ColumnValues.Add(2)
ColumnValues.Add(0)
ColumnValues.Add(0)
ColumnValues.Add(0)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)
ColumnsFinished.Add(False)

    Dim mostCommon As Integer = ColumnValues.Where(Function(i) Not ColumnsFinished.Contains(i)). 'Exclude finished rows
        GroupBy(Function(x) x). 'Grouping same items
        OrderByDescending(Function(grp) grp.Count()). 'now getting frequency of a value
        ThenBy(Function(grp) grp.Key). 'Make sure we get the smallest key first
        [Select](Function(bcd) bcd.Key). '
        FirstOrDefault() 'Finally, taking the most frequent value
```

Here is a image of the suitation

[image: test]

Comment: *"if all common values are same"*, well of course they are same, otherwise they would not be common. Do you mean "if there is more than one"? Also it would be easier to handle if you had one single list with a tuple instead of two lists that you have to keep in sync: `List(Of (Value As Integer, IsFinished As Boolean))`

Comment: Not all commons are unique you can have 2, 2s and 5, 0s or 1s and still pick 2s or 1s

Comment: I guess I would use the word "repeated" where you are using "common", but I'm still not certain what the smallest most repeated value means. Especially give the example in your previous comment where I would assume "the smallest most repeated value" is 0 because both 0 and 1 are the most repeated values (repeated 5 times) but 0 is smaller than 1.

Comment: 0's are used as fall-backs if the common values / repeated values are complete, kinda like a brute forcer that goes into the next character length when it runs out of combinations.